# hide keyboard for text field in swift programming language

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have little experience in Objective-C. I want to hide the keyboard for a text field using the Swift programming language.

I also tried this

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
{
    return true;
}
```

But the method is not getting triggered when I hit return. Anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180954/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-swift-on-pressing-return-key

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close iOS Keyboard by touching anywhere using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think the Problem is with setting the Delegate.

Please set textfield Delegate to your ViewController like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
```

and then create the IBOutlet for your text field like this

```
@IBOutlet var txtTest : UITextField = nil
```

make sure that it is connected to your text field on your view in storyboard.

finally set its Delegate using

```
txtTest.delegate=self
```

We are almost done. Now place this delegate function into your class.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
    {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: you need to set UITextFieldDelegate protocol on your class > class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { }

Comment: @Rv15 This may be a Swift 1.2 change but: textFieldShouldReturn takes a non-optional UITextField parameter so the '!' needs to be removed.

Answer (score 11):

Just override the UIViewController method called "touchesBegan" and set endEditing to true. Just like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Also @Rahul Patel approximation is useful to hide keyboard, when return is pressed

Comment: Method signature is is now
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)

Answer (score 10):

In order to hide the keyboard when you pressed a button, you need to use the following function.

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

This works when a button is pressed.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: A great place to use this is in a tap gesture action on the whole view. This way, when the user clicks anywhere above the keyboard the keyboard will disappear.

Answer (score 6):

Here we go:

1. Add a textField to your View
2. Create a new Swift file
3. Set this new file as a Class for that particular View
4. Add a TextField to your View
5. Create an Outlet for the textfield (my is named "txtField" !)
6. Substitute any code in the Swift Class file with this:

   ```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit

   //01 create delegation
   class MyViewController2: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!=nil

       override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // additional setup after loading the view

         //02 set delegate to textfield
         txtField.delegate = self
       }

       //03 textfield func for the return key
       func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
         txtField.resignFirstResponder()
         return true;
       }

       //textfield func for the touch on BG
       override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
         txtField.resignFirstResponder()
         self.view.endEditing(true)
       }

       override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         //dispose of any resources that can be recreated
       }
     }
   ```

   7. Try it out, be happy & say thanks !

Comment: What if you have two UITextFields? Or six?

Comment: For some reason, when I set the txtField.delegate = self , I can not type within that textfield once I run the app  :/

Answer (score 4):

Now In Swift 3/4/5, the easiest methods are

**Method 1:** called when 'return' key pressed.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
 {
 textField1.resignFirstResponder()
 textField2.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }
```

**Method 2:** called when 'return' key pressed.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
    {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true;
    }
```

**Method 3:** Global Method Write in view did load

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add this. Other wise its not work.

```
UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate
```

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: I like the 3rd method 

Answer (score 3):

In simple way to hide the keyboard just override the UIView "touchBegan method". So when you tap any where in the view keyboard is hide.
here is the sample code.. (Swift 3.0 Updated code)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
{
   self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @spfursich said, The best way is, when user touch anywhere above the keyboard the keyboard will disappear. Here is the code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func DismissKeyboard(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add UITextFieldDelegate to the class declaration:

  class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
- Connect the textfield or write it programmatically

  @IBOutlet weak var userText: UITextField!
- set your view controller as the text fields delegate in view did load:

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.userText.delegate = self
  }
  ```
- Add the following function

  ```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(userText: UITextField!) -> Bool {
      userText.resignFirstResponder()
      return true;
  }
  ```

  with all this your keyboard will begin to dismiss by touching outside the textfield aswell as by pressing return key.

Comment: please don't copy the exact same answer to several questions - chances are that either they don't really fit all or the questions are duplicates (and should be flagged as such)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set `delegate` for your textfield then you need to include `resignFirstResponder()` to hide keyboard when press return button of keybaord.

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
 {
   textField .resignFirstResponder()
   return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to have the "return" key execute code.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    performAction()
    return true;
}

func performAction(){

//execute code for your action inside this function

}
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:
add event "Did end on exit" from connections inspector of your TextField
and connect it to method from relevant ViewController

*In my example I connect it to method called 'ended'*

declare sender as UITextField and then call sender.resignFirstResponder();
Like this:

```
@IBAction func ended (sender: UITextField){ sender.resignFirstResponder(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have solved the problem, that when **keypad opens and the view gets hidden behind the keypad**.... **that time we need to change the UI constraints dynamically** in order to make the whole view visible. In my case i am changing the bottonConstraint of the `UITextField` dynamically.

*So, here goes the complete code. I have one `UITextView` and `UITextField` on `UIViewController` to work on for just testing...*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextView!

      /*Height Constraint for textField*/
    @IBOutlet weak var bottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var defaultHeight:CGFloat = 0.0;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        defaultHeight = bottom.constant;

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        textView.resignFirstResponder();
        textField.resignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        resignFirstResponder()
        print("touched began")
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        resignFirstResponder()
        print("text view did end editing")
    }

    func textViewShouldEndEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        resignFirstResponder()
        print("text view should end editing")
        return true;
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("text field should return")
        resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        resignFirstResponder()
        print("did end editing")
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("keyboard will show.............")
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            let a = keyboardSize.height;
            self.bottom.constant = a + defaultHeight;
            self.view.updateConstraints();
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(nofication:NSNotification)
    {
        print("keyboard will hide................")
        bottom.constant = defaultHeight;
        self.view.updateConstraints();

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call your UIAlertController, place condition in the completion handler if you'd like to hide the keyboard.

```
self.present('nameOfYourUIAlertController', animated: true, completion: {
    if condition == true {
        'nameOfYourUIAlertController'.textFields![0].resignFirstResponder()
    }
})
```

This works great for me.