# how to dismiss keyboard iOS on a table view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

What is a good way to dismiss this keyboard when the user touches outside of it? I tried the touches began method but this does not work. The textfieldshouldreturn method works okay though. I can't think of any other ways of doing this. Can someone please help me out here I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

```
import UIKit


var courseCatalog : [String] = Array<String>()


class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate , UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var searchTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        courseCatalog = ["Accounting", "Administration" , "American Studies" , "Anthropology" , "Arabic" , "Art" , "Aerospace Studies" , "American Sign Language" , "Biology" , "Child Development" , "Chemistry" , "Chinese" , "Criminal Justice", "Communication Studies" , "Computer Science", "Computer Engineering"]

        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        println("Home Tab View Controller")

        searchTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return courseCatalog.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = courseCatalog[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


        self.searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

        searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true

    }





}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide keyboard for text field in swift programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908966/hide-keyboard-for-text-field-in-swift-programming-language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a tap gesture recognizer to your table view that closes the keyboard when it's fired:

```
//Somewhere in setup
UITapGestureRecognizer *viewTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeKeyboard)];
viewTap.cancelsTouchesInView = FALSE;
[myTableView addGestureRecognizer:viewTap];

//Somewhere else in your class
-(void)closeKeyboard {

    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: I added a tap gesture recognizer to close the keyboard but now the user can not tap on any of the contents of the table view

Comment: @MbusiHlatshwayo Did you set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `FALSE`?

Answer (score 2):

If your background is a UIView, you can change it to a UIControl in the identity inspector and send it to an action that resigns the first responder.

Since your background is a UITableView you should add a rightBarButtonItem to your navigationBar like 'Cancel' or 'Done' and send it to a method that resigns first responder*.

*Your first responder is the field the user is typing in.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Swift:

```
textField.resignFirstResponder();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

This will dismiss the keyboard when the 'return' button is pressed on the keyboard.

Hope this can help you.