# How to dissmiss keyboard in text view in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to dismiss keyboard in text view using accessory views with done button but keyboard is not showing done button in it.Actually i have writen my code in textViewDidBeginEditing using inputAccessoryView.Here is my code.

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        currentTextView = textView //This is to tell the current position in text view

```
    var indexPath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 2)
    let cell:EventTableTableViewCell = EventTableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! EventTableTableViewCell
    cell.messageTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No


    let keyboardDoneButton = UIToolbar()
    keyboardDoneButton.sizeToFit()

    let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("doneButton"))



    var toolbarButtons = [item]
    //Put the buttons into the ToolBar and display the tool bar
    keyboardDoneButton.setItems(toolbarButtons, animated: false)
        keyboardDoneButton.userInteractionEnabled = true

//cell.messageTextView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButton
    textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButton

    }


}
func doneButton()
{
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)

}
```

Comment: You are going to need to update your question with some more details if you want to get any useful help.

Comment: You need to set the done button as part of the keyboard

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide keyboard for text field in swift programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908966/hide-keyboard-for-text-field-in-swift-programming-language)

Answer (score 0):

```
_textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the keyboard in IB? 
Storyboard > Textfield > Attributes Inspector > Return Key > Done

Implement the delegate method:

```
- textfieldShouldReturn:
```

Found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn: