# iOS hide keyboard on touch textfield swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2

I want to hide the keyboard if the user clicks on a textfield. Does anybody have an idea how to do that in swift 2?

Comment: I did't get your idea. You dont want your textfield will be selected by user?

Comment: It should be selected by the user but i don't want to show the keyboard. Instead of the keyboard i want to show a picker. I know how to do that with a button but i want a textfield so that i can put the value of the picker inside the textfield

Comment: @Philipp a button still might be a better choice, as you can easily change the button title after you select something from the picker. Overriding default behaviour on a text field is not a very good idea, but if you still want to do so, consider using `inputView` property on the text field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide keyboard for text field in swift programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908966/hide-keyboard-for-text-field-in-swift-programming-language)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate @NimitParekh, Philipp doesn't want the textField to appear, he wants something else to appear instead of the keyboard.

Comment: I agree with DominikHadl that's the best option. Or you set `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the textfield, and when a tap occurs,  you do what you need it to do (show a picker). Let us know if you may need that code instead! @Philipp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to set the text field delegate and return `false` in this [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldBeginEditing:) method:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

This will prevent the keyboard from showing. You can also place the code to open the picker in that method.

Comment: Yes, definitely.This keeps it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Showing a text field on screen doesn't mean that only a text field is there. You could have a text field as a sub view, with user interaction disabled. Then, add a transparent button as a sibling view with the same frame (ensuring it's in front). When the button is tapped, which from a user point of view is tapping the text field, you can show your picker.

The text field also offers direct support for displaying a picker view by allowing you to set its [inputView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView).

Comment: This is not very elegant. There has to be a better way.

Comment: @NicolasMiari That's the direct support way I added, just needed to get the link. The multiple view way can be very effective depending on the UI interaction required.