# Keyboard issue on my app

Tags: swift

I just made a simple app where you type things in four boxes and can randomly select one. After typing in the boxes I need the keyboard to go away so people can see what the result is, but the on-screen keyboard just stays. Is this something I need to change in the files of the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide keyboard for text field in swift programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908966/hide-keyboard-for-text-field-in-swift-programming-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `resignFirstResponder()` property of the text field.

Comment: The problem with that is that i can not assign value of type bool to uitextfield.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the keyboard when a tap occurred outside the text field,
you can use an `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backgroundTapped(_:)))
  view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

func backgroundTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  view.endEditing(true)
}
```