# How to never show the keyboard

Tags: swift3, uikit

I made my own keyboard by buttons and I want to never show the Apple keyboard even by touching the text field? How is that done?

Answer (score 1):

Set your custom keyboard view as the inputView of the textfield.

```
textField.inputView = customView
```

Then the keyboard will show with your custom view. And you get all the animations and stuff for free.

If you don't want your custom view in the iOS keyboard you might need to check out something like what this guy explains in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28024248/4812253)