# Swift: SearchTextField & IQKeyboardManager - hide keyboard on tap

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

I have this problem:

I want to show the list of a `SearchTextField` without the keyboard.
I'm using [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) & [SearchTextField](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField). I tried several solutions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908966/hide-keyboard-for-text-field-in-swift-programming-language) but they don't work...

Probably I have to change something on a library, but I don't get it and the developer is not answering...

Thanks!

Comment: Have tried using self.view.endEditing = true

Comment: The default behavior is that keyboard appear when you enter to UITextField, please add some details to your scenario what exactly you want to do.

Comment: if you want to show list of searchtextfield you can show, the keyboard will be hidden until you enter editing mode.