# Why is the textFieldShouldReturn function not being called?

Tags: swift, keyboard

The `textFieldShouldReturn` function is not being called at all: there are no errors but the keyboard does not respond at all.

My case is different from [How to hide keyboard in swift on pressing return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180954/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-swift-on-pressing-return-key) as in my case nothing is happening at all and other cases are in Objective-C.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

textField is an outlet to a text field on my storyboard. I also tried `self.endEditing` instead of `resignFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The rest of this answer is still very useful, and I'll leave it there as it can potentially help other askers... but here, I missed the obvious problem with this specific example...

We're not calling `resignFirstResponder` on the text field.  We're calling it on the view controller.  We need to call it on the text field, so modify your code to look like this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

---

A `UITextField` will only call the `textFieldShouldReturn` property on the object which is its delegate.

We can fix this programmatically by adding a `viewDidLoad` method to set that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textField.delegate = self
}
```

But we can also set this up via the storyboard at build time.

Right click on the textfield to check and see whether or not the delegate has been set:

[image]

If that circle next to `delegate` is unfilled, we haven't set the delegate for our `UITextField` yet.

To set the delegate, hover over this circle.  It will change to a plus sign.  Now click and drag to the view controller that you want to delegate the text field (the view controller the text field is part of).

[image]

When you've appropriately hooked the view controller up as a delegate, this menu should look like this:

[image]

Comment: ... plus be sure that the "ViewController" class supports the UITextFieldDelegate. So it should be `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {...`

Comment: Aah.. the key was extending UITextFieldDelegate, but you must implement the delegate for every textField, for eg. `self.textField.delegate = self`. which I forgot to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If using Swift 3+, you have to add an underscore before the first property. Like:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

This is also very well documented in the Apple Documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn

Answer (score 5):

I'm enrolled in a Swift 4 Udemy course, and the instructor said to add the UITextFieldDelegate class for the ViewController in addition to Cntrl - dragging from the textField to the ViewController button and selecting delegate.

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add textfield.resign... then even if `return true` is `return false` it still works.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in my case. I accidentally enable hardware keyboard. Make sure you unchecked "Connect to hardware keyboard" in order for the keyboard to show up in the simulator.

Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect to hardware keyboard

Hope this will help others too!

Answer (score 1):

You can set all textFields delegate in a loop:

```
var tF: [UITextField] = []

tf = [my1TextField, my2TextField, my3TextField]

for textField in tf {
    textField.delegate = self
}
```