# how to hide keyboard after clicking return in swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, hide

I want to hide the keyboard after clicking the return button, and I have searched on website and wrote the same code as it shows on the internet. However, the keyboard still didn't hide. I don't know why?

[this is the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUAfa.png)

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaN6F.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as picture. Copy and paste the text in here.

Comment: The first question is: Have you set your `UITextField` delegate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide keyboard in swift on pressing return key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180954/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-swift-on-pressing-return-key)

Answer (score 0):

I think like @paulvs said is to set the delegate

so drag the text field on the storyboard to the "donut" at the top of the screen and select delegate

then create and IBOutlet for the text field by being on the storyboard and then tapping the assistant editor...it looks like two overlapping circles
Control drag the text field to your viewcontroller and make sure it is on Outlet and then name it textField

Next set the delegate by setting it equal to itself
so

```
textField.delegate = self
```

then create a delegate function (should auto fill as you type) but it is 
func textfieldshouldreturn

inside that func do this

```
textField.resignfirstresponder()
```

then return true

Comment: found this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908966/hide-keyboard-for-text-field-in-swift-programming-language

Answer (score 0):

try to confirm: 1. inherit from UITextFieldDelegate; 2. set the current view controller self as delegate; 3. return false at the overrided func textfieldshouldreturn that you called.