# Hide keyboard automatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to automatically hide keyboard in swift after inputting four characters? I actually have a code that hides the keyboard but the user has to click anywhere on the screen. Here's the code:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-uitextfield-changes Have the method check the current length. When it is the proper size, dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide keyboard in swift on pressing return key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180954/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-swift-on-pressing-return-key)

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap No, that's not a duplicate since the OP isn't asking how to dismiss the keyboard when return is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question correctly, Consider below example code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtF: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txtF.delegate = self
        txtF.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    }


    func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == txtF {

            if textField.text?.characters.count == 4 {

                self.txtF.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if textField == txtF {

            if textField.text?.characters.count > 3 {

                self.txtF.resignFirstResponder()
                return false
            } else {

                return true
            }
        } else {

            return true
        }
    }
}
```

With above code keyboard will hide when textField have 4 characters and after that if user again tap on textField keyboard will pop up be user will not able to enter any text into textField and keyboard will hide again.

Result will be:

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: why so complicated

Comment: This fails if the user pastes in more than 4 characters into the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to hide the keyboard or a numberpad.
First you need a button and you need to make it the size of the screen.Send it to the back of the scene and connect it to an IBAction.Then you code should look like this:

```
@IBAction func HideKeyboard(sender: AnyObject) {
   YourKeyboardHere.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

This should work for all types of keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
// Outlet to textfield, editing changed
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    if sender.text?.characters.count == 4 {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    // Optional if you don't want the user to paste in more than 4 characters
    else if sender.text?.characters.count > 4   {
        sender.text = nil
    }
}
```

I also recommend you setting the

```
textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
```

so the textField gets cleared when the user clicks on it again.

Comment: This will fail if the user pastes in more than 4 characters into the text field.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know if this is a big deal or nor. I added an optional fix anyways.

Answer (score -2):

You should use textfield delegate `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` something like,

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


if (textField.text.length == 4) {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

return YES;
}
```

In Swift,

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {



        if textField.text?.characters.count == 4 {

            textField.resignFirstResponder()

        } 
    return true
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: A String doesn't have a member named length.

Comment: In swift use: textField.text?.characters.count or NSString(string: textField.text!).length

Comment: OP is coding in Swift, not in Objective-C.

Comment: Updated for swift...!!

Comment: This code won't work. There are many conditions where this will allow more than 4 characters and many cases where it won't dismiss the keyboard.