# To dismiss keyboard is there any difference between using `resignFirstResponder` and `endEditing`?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I read this question: [How to hide keyboard in swift on pressing return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180954/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-swift-on-pressing-return-key)

and basically there are 2 ways to answer:

- `self.view.endEditing(true)`
- `textField.resignFirstResponder()`

They both get the job done independently. But do they have any other difference/caveats or places that one one work and the other won't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.view.endEditing(true)` is less efficient because it will cycle through the entire view hierarchy and makes sure anything that can be a firstRepsonder has resigned it.

If you know which item is currently the responder, it is more efficient and better practice to call `resignFirstResponder` on it directly.

Comment: OK, but if I have multiple textFields like: firstName, LastName, Address, etc. and then at the end I have a **`submit`** button, would doing `self.view.endEditing` be a better choice

Comment: @Honey since not all of those text fields can be the first responder at the same time, when `submit` is selected only one will be the first responder, thus you should call `resignFirstResponder` on it. While I don't think you'll _see_ any performance impact by using `endEditing`, it's generally better "practice" to know which text field is active and only resign on that one.

Comment: It's a really interesting question.  I **cannot see any reason** to ever use resignFirstResponder.  I believe they will deprecate it in the future.  (Regarding the efficiency aspect, you're talking a handful of items, it's irrelevant.) (If for some reason you happen to want to, you can call `endEditing` on just that one item.)