# How can I collapse a keyboard on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, textview, uikeyboard

I saw this question: 
[How to hide keyboard in swift on pressing return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180954/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-swift-on-pressing-return-key). But it dismisses the keyboard entirely.

I'm looking for this:

[image]

Comment: In most instances, swiping down just above the top of the keyboard will dismiss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't exist on the iPhone (nor on the iPod Touch).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in iOS. You may have to write custom keyboard to achieve this.